# Resize a table in Excel (ie. add columns to an existing table) without using the mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2013

I often use tables in Excel 2013. Adding a column on the right hand side of the table usually works fine--the new column is added to the table automatically.

However, when I add a column on the left-hand side of the table (or occasionally when I do something else crazy), I need to use Resize Table to redefine the dimensions of my table.

I'd like to be able to do this without taking my hands off the keyboard, ie. without using the mouse.

Opening the Resize Table dialog is simple: alt, jt, i. However, once the dialog is open, if I use the arrow keys to try to move the cursor so I can change one character in the address range, Excel moves the cursor on the spreadsheet, thinking I want to select a range of cells.

As such, unless I want to delete the entire data range with the dialog and retype it all (I don't), I have to use the mouse to move the cursor to the column address I want to change.

Is there any way to avoid using the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

**To Insert a column in an Excel table** (individual key-presses):

`Alt - i - c`

---

**Expand an Excel table to include an additional columns with data in them: (without using the mouse)**

Go to the top-left cell of your table.

```
`Ctrl - Up - Left`
```

Open the Resize Table Dialog (as you mentioned)

```
`Alt - j - t - i`
```

Then to add existing columns to the table:

```
`(Press and hold) Shift - (Tap) Right_Arrow (press once for each column you want to add) - Enter`
```

Comment: That inserts a new column (which is great), but it doesn't add an existing column to a table.

Comment: So you have a column (outside of the table) with data in it that you want to get added to an existing table?

Comment: Modified my answer to add existing columns.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because I think it's the best answer and it really does answer the original question. It doesn't get you into the Resize Table dialog, which is what I was really hoping for, but it works well enough, I guess.

Comment: Changed to unaccept this answer--after a bit more using testing, I realized it doesn't help with the very common situation of shrinking a table based on rows you want to remove.